# SimpleModal plugin is causing jQuery conflict with Spring DWR

Tags: jquery, conflict, simplemodal

I'm using SimpleModal plugin (http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) for generating a simple modal dialog. Now the application I'm using this in had some previous code that uses Spring MVC - DWR Ajax framework. I believe it uses jQuery internally.

Now when I include the jQuery file in this project and use the plugin, the plugin works fine but it is breaking the existing AJAX implementations in the project (which I assume is because I'm including the jQuery file again.) How do I resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more details I can't be sure what the problem is.  A good place to start would be to make sure the '$' shortcut is not causing any conflicts.  You can try using JQuery.noConflict(); as described on the [JQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries).

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I did. My issue is resolved already. Here's a link that I found useful and others might also find useful if they face the same issue. Basically it uses the jQuery.noConflict() approach as well. 

http://serkanguler.info/2009/11/04/how-to-resolve-conflicts-of-dwr-and-jquery/